# Difference between @InjectMocks and @Autowired usage in mockito?

Tags: java, spring, dependency-injection, mockito, spring-ioc

When I was writing test case using the Mockito and Junit, I was using the `@InjectMocks` for the class to be tested. In other parts of project, I also see `@Autowired` is being used for the class to be tested.

When can I use `@InjectMocks` and `@Autowired`? What is the difference between two when we are trying to use them with class to be tested?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

`@InjectMocks` is a Mockito mechanism for injecting declared fields in the **test** class into matching fields in the class **under test**. It doesn't require the class under test to be a Spring component.

`@Autowired` is Spring's annotation for autowiring a bean into a production, non-test class.

If you wanted to leverage the `@Autowired` annotations in the class under test, another approach would be to use [springockito](https://github.com/springockito/springockito) which allows you to declare mock beans so that they will be autowired into the class under test the same way that Spring would autowire the bean.  But typically that's not necessary.

Comment: +1 as I had not heard of springockito which looks nice and clean.

Comment: Springockito is really nice, I never use it as I favor unit tests. However I recently (a few month back) heard that springockito had some bugs.

Comment: springockito seems to not maintained, last update is on 2017 and also the site is down.

Answer (score 13):

`@InjectMocks` annotation tells to Mockito to inject all mocks (objects annotated by `@Mock` annotation) into fields of testing object. Mockito uses Reflection for this.

`@Autowired` annotation tells to Spring framework to inject bean from its IoC container. Spring also uses reflection for this when it is private field injection.
You can even use even use `@Inject` annotation (part of Java EE specification) with the same effect.

But I would suggest to look at benefits of [Constructor injection over Field injection](http://lkrnac.net/blog/2014/02/promoting-constructor-field-injection/). In that case you don't need to use `@InjectMocks` at all, because you can pass mocks into testing object via constructor. There wouldn't be Reflection needed under the hood in your test nor in production.

If you want to create integration test with subset of Spring beans I would suggest to take a look at `@DirtiesContext` annotation. It is part of Spring framework module commonly called "Spring Test".

Comment: is there any suggestion to use one over the other? or usage of either `@Autowired` or `@InjectMocks` is fine in Integration testing.

Comment: @sub, notice that this answer is nowadays obsolete: take a loot at this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/69281202/1919879